# How long should I wait for Prospero registration?

Tags: review-articles, meta-analysis, pre-registration

I am currently in process of conducting two systematic review and meta-analysis. I have filled in the registration of my reviews in Prospero, yet I have not received any response from the Prospero. I filled in the registration nearly one year ago (first review) and six months ago (second review). Should I reach the Prospero office to follow-up my Prospero record? Or should I wait further?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should contact them if you have not heard from them after even one month. Prospero contact details are here: https://www.crd.york.ac.uk/PROSPERO/#contactuspage